# Visual Studio undesired shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

Ok, I found nothing about this and I have no idea how that happened. When I work in Visual Studio 2017 and I want to type an opening curly bracket '{' I hit the right "Alt" key + the double quote key, its the key that is immediately to the left of the Return key on my keyboard. My keyboard language is 
"French Canada". That used to work perfectly and it still does anywhere but in VS2017.

[image: Keyboard Layout]

Since 10min ago, that combination of keys now comment/uncomment the current line and puts the cursor/caret on the next line...

I have no idea how to undo whatever I might have done that changed the behavior of that key combo.

Comment: Alt + 0123 and Alt + 0125. Have fun programming.

Comment: On French keyboard settings right alt + 4 is {, right alt + 'plus' is }. On French Canadian keyboard settings I can use right alt + 7 or 8

Comment: Still no idea why the combination of keys that I've always used to make a '{' stoped working tho.

Comment: Humm finally found a way to make things normal again... I went in the resharper options, under Keyboard & Menus and selected "None" under Resharper Ultimate keyboard scheme. the "Visual Studio" scheme has been selected for a year without issues, so I still wonder why that suddenly changed yesterday but at least now I can type my curly brackets '{' the same way I always did.

Answer (score 0):

Humm finally found a way to make things normal again... I went in the resharper options, under Keyboard & Menus and selected "None" under Resharper Ultimate keyboard scheme. the "Visual Studio" scheme has been selected for a year without issues, so I still wonder why that suddenly changed yesterday but at least now I can type my curly brackets '{' the same way I always did.

Comment: What do you use Resharper for? I looked it up and the features are basically already built into Visual Studio

Comment: I'd say I don't use it that much honestly. Mainly to get the suggestions on how to rewrite some code lines more efficiently.